# PAGEFLIP on AS3 XML can't be seen on IE and FIREFOX

Tags: javascript, html, xml, flash, actionscript

I have an issue and i want to see if someone can help me...

I'm using a PAGEFLIP downloaded from: http://pageflip.hu/ on this project that is inside of a JOOMLA article: http://estudiantes.iems.edu.mx/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=334

MY ISSUE IS THAT I CAN SEE THE PAGEFLIP ONLY ON CHROME AND SAFARI BUT IT DOESN'T RUN ON IE AND FIREFOX, this is not a problem with compatibility, cause it runs on local on Firefox and IE...

I was searching and i think that the issue comes out when I change the URL... This is the ORIGINAL CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>PageFlip4</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="css/pageflip_scalable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars = {};
            flashvars.XMLFileName = "pageflipdata.xml";
            flashvars.DataFolder = "pageflipdata/";

            if (swfobject.getQueryParamValue("page")) {
                flashvars.StartPage = swfobject.getQueryParamValue("page");
            } else {
                flashvars.StartPage = "1";
            }

            flashvars.StartAutoFlip = "true";
            flashvars.AutoStart = "true";
            var params = {};

            params.scale = "noscale";
            params.salign = "TL";
            params.wmode = "transparent";
            params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
            params.allowfullscreen = "true";
            params.menu = "true";
            params.bgcolor = "#FFFFFF";

            var attributes = {};
            swfobject.embedSWF("pageFlip.swf", "pageflip", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
        </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />      
      <script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/lightbox++.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            function GroupDelegate(id) {
                var objLink = document.getElementById(id);
                Lightbox.prototype.start(objLink);
            }
            function LightboxDelegate(url,caption) {
                var objLink = document.createElement('a');
                objLink.setAttribute('href',url);
                objLink.setAttribute('rel','lightbox');
                objLink.setAttribute('title',caption);
                Lightbox.prototype.start(objLink);
            }
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="pageflip" style="margin: 0;"></div>
        <a id="group1" href="pageflipdata/pages/demo_page_A.png" rel="lightbox[demoGroup1]" title="Page A, group Called from PageFlip Hotspot"></a>
        <a id="group2" href="pageflipdata/pages/demo_page_B.png" rel="lightbox[demoGroup1]" title="Page B, group Called from PageFlip Hotspot"></a>
        <a id="group3" href="pageflipdata/pages/demo_page_C.png" rel="lightbox[demoGroup1]" title="Page C, group Called from PageFlip Hotspot"></a>     
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't see it on Firefox and IE When I change the URL from this SCRIPT lines (this is my code online):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var flashvars = {};
            flashvars.XMLFileName = "pageflipdata.xml";
            flashvars.DataFolder = "http://estudiantes.iems.edu.mx/cired/swfs/ae/fl/noumeno/obj/pageflipdata/";

            if (swfobject.getQueryParamValue("page")) {
                flashvars.StartPage = swfobject.getQueryParamValue("page");
            } else {
                flashvars.StartPage = "1";
            }

            flashvars.StartAutoFlip = "true";
            flashvars.AutoStart = "true";
            var params = {};

            params.scale = "noscale";
            params.salign = "TL";
            params.wmode = "transparent";
            params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
            params.allowfullscreen = "true";
            params.menu = "true";
            params.bgcolor = "#FFFFFF";

            var attributes = {};
            swfobject.embedSWF("http://estudiantes.iems.edu.mx/cired/swfs/ae/fl/noumeno/obj/pageFlip.swf", "pageflip", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);

        </script>
```

So, what i think is incorrect is the way i write it, kind of syntax issue.

Somebody has an idea of what can i try to solve this. Thank you so much! ;)

Comment: The problem appears to be how you embed it, not having anything to do with Flash.  I will dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving full path for XML

or can use HTML like